# Heroku Rails app makes request to http endpoint instead of https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, httparty

I have a Rails app that uses the gem [Httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). It makes a call to Stubhub's API with a base URI of https://api.stubhub.com. The app behaves as expected locally and makes successful calls.  However, when deployed to Heroku I get 403 forbidden error -- it is making the request to http instead of https.  Is Heroku forcing the GET request to an http endpoint?  Why?  How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Ever get this solved? I'm running into the same issue (albeit with Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with a similar issue for months now.  It recently came to my attention that the SSL version could cause this timeout.  Using HTTParty I resolved this like this:

```
HTTParty.get('url_here', ssl_version: :SSLv3).body
```

I am unsure as to which ssl_version token you will need, but in my case, this fixed the problem.  Take a look here for a little more information about where this came from:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/257

A warning:  SSLv3 is not secure, but that does not stop people from continuing to use it.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking a look at this old post!  I'll give this a try tonight.  This really stalled my project